# Isomorphism of irreducible R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a $k-$algebra and $M,N$ two irreducible $R-$modules, isomorphic as vector spaces. If we know that for every $r\in R$ we have the same eigenvalues on $M$ and $N$ (with multiplicities) is it true that $M\simeq N$?

I have two thoughts:

1. Denoting $St(m)=\{ rm=m \mid r\in R\}$, if we have $St(m)=St(n)$ for some $m\in M, n\in N$, we could find an isomorphism that sends $m$ to $n$ and is extended by $f(rm)=rf(m)$ (every element of $M$ is $rm$ for some $r$ by irreducibility). I cannot prove the existence of such a pair though.
2. If $R$ was commutative, we could simultaneously diagonalize all the actions according to some basis and take the isomorphism of vector spaces that sends the one basis to the other. This will then be an isomorphism of modules. I cannot extend that to the general case.

Comment: You should probably be more careful in checking that the map you describe in (2) is an isomorphism of modules.

Comment: If we choose a basis that simultaneously diagonalizes all actions with the corresponding eigenvalues, then all actions' values agree on the elements of that basis, thus on the whole module. Isn't that correct?

Comment: If you can simultaneously diagonalize all elements of $R$ on a module and the module is simple, then the module is $1$-dimensional, for clearly the subspace spanned by one of the common eigenvectors is a submodule.

Comment: (It would probably be useful if youmade any hypotheses on the field, on the algebra and on the module explicit… If $k$ algebraically closed? $R$ finite dimensional? etc)

Comment: In the specific question, $R$ is the Hecke Algebra of a $p-$adic group, and $M,N$ are irreducible $p-$adic representations. We can assume $G$ compact to have an easier to tackle problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the commutative algebra $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ and the modules $R/(x)$ and $R/(y)$.

Comment: You are right. My mistake in 2 was that I did not consider that maybe an action is not diagonizable. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that —as I always do :-( — I interpreted *irreducible* to mean *indecomposable*, and my guess is you did not intend that!

Comment: Actually the irreducible modules I am referring to come from group representations... I am new to the field. I am not sure I can even use modules with torsion as a counterexample, I think it actually should be a counterexample based on finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field...

Comment: And it is true, now I see that these modules are not irreducible... The linear subspace $\{0,x\} is preserved under both actions.

Comment: @IoannisZolas, I don't think your comment makes sense, really. In any case, $R/(x)$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field $k$.

Comment: But it is indecomposable, true, but not irreducible, since the linear subspace generated by $x$ is an $R-$ invariant submodule of $R/(y)$. So it is not a counterexample to the question.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly the point of my very first comment...